# How to post file in JSON

Tags: json, file, c#-4.0

I have a JSON format like

{
"Entity_ID":string,
"Name" :string,
"Key" : string,
"file":file
}

How should I pass value of datatype file in JSON ?

My Source URL is like: http://abc.com/api/images.json?api_key=special-key

Also What will I do if I want to test response in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to achieve it:

1. Convert your file into `base 64 string` using some external API's at client side

   You will need to read the bytes from that File and convet it into string and  put that string into your JSONObject.
2. Then on server side you can do reverse process of converting base64 string to file.

   Or With HTML5 you CAN make file uploads with Ajax and jQuery.
   Have a look at following post:

   [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery/8758614#8758614)